# Calculate stdev for a row and previous row in pandas without series error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Here is my dataset

```
Date,p1Close,p2Close,spread,movingAverage
2022-02-28,5,10,2,NaN
2022-03-01,2,6,3,2.5
2022-03-02,4,8,2,2.5
2022-03-03,2,8,4,3
```

I am trying to create a new column in pandas data frame that is equal to the standard deviation between `spread` from previous row and current row.

```
    df['standardDeviation'] = statistics.stdev(df['spread'], df['spread'].shift(1))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/statistics.py", line 797, in stdev
    var = variance(data, xbar)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/statistics.py", line 740, in variance
    T, ss = _ss(data, xbar)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/statistics.py", line 684, in _ss
    T, total, count = _sum((x-c)**2 for x in data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/statistics.py", line 166, in _sum
    for n, d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/statistics.py", line 248, in _exact_ratio
    raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__))
TypeError: can't convert type 'Series' to numerator/denominator
```

I believe it is because I am using `shift(1)` and on the first calculation it doesn't have a `shift(1)` value so it errors out. Not sure how to approach solving this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just use `<column>.rolling(2).std()`:

```
df['standardDeviation'] = df['spread'].rolling(2).std()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date  p1Close  p2Close  spread  movingAverage  standardDeviation
0  2022-02-28        5       10       2            NaN                NaN
1  2022-03-01        2        6       3            2.5           0.707107
2  2022-03-02        4        8       2            2.0           0.707107
3  2022-03-03        2        8       4            3.0           1.414214
```

Answer (score 1):

@richardec's answer is the best solution but for your specific question, `statistics.stdev` expects an iterator, so you'll need to pass in pairs:

```
df['stdev'] = [statistics.stdev(pair) for pair in zip(df['spread'], df['spread'].shift())]
```

Output:

```
         Date  p1Close  p2Close  spread  movingAverage     stdev
0  2022-02-28        5       10       2            NaN       NaN
1  2022-03-01        2        6       3            2.5  0.707107
2  2022-03-02        4        8       2            2.0  0.707107
3  2022-03-03        2        8       4            3.0  1.414214
```